# package.path not being set properly

Tags: lua, shared-libraries

I have a situation where depending on where I define my package.path, my code fails.  I can't understand why.

I have the following file structure:

```
/usr/share/zaf/mytestapp/main.lua
/usr/share/zaf/mytestapp/lib/user.lua
/usr/share/zaf/mytestapp/lib/admin_user.lua
```

**The Code that Works**

Inside main, I have the following code:

```
module (..., package.seeall)
package.path = package.path .. ';/usr/share/zaf/mytestapp/?.lua'
local user = require "lib.user"

list_devices = function(user_id, enduser, start_record, record_count)
   local devices = {}
   local success

   local res, err = pcall(function()   
        if enduser then         
            success, devices  = user:getDevices(user_id)   
        end
    end) --end pcall

   return devices
end
```

This code works... the system is able to find user.lua and return a list of devices.

**The Code that Does't Work**

I want to change the code so that it loads the library only ***after*** I know what type of user it is.  Notice how I've moved the location of the code that instantiates the user object to inside the 'if' statement, but I've kept the package.path line where it is.

```
module (..., package.seeall)
package.path = package.path .. ';/usr/share/zaf/mytestapp/?.lua'

list_devices = function(user_id, enduser, start_record, record_count)
   local devices = {}
   local success

   local res, err = pcall(function()   
        if enduser then         
            local user = require "lib.user" 
            success, devices  = user:getDevices(user_id)   
        else
            --admin
            local admin_user = require 'lib.admin'  
            admin_user:get_devices()
        end
    end) --end pcall
   return devices
end
```

This code fails because it can't find the lib.user module anymore... and I don't understand why.  I'm still learning lua so you'll have to pardon me if this is a real 101 question. 
If I move the package.path line to inside the if statement, it works... like so:

```
    if enduser then         
            package.path = package.path .. ';/usr/share/zaf/mytestapp/?.lua'
        local user = require "lib.user" 
        success, devices  = user:getDevices(user_id)   
    else
        --admin
        local admin_user = require 'lib.admin'  
        success, devices = admin_user:get_devices()
    end
```

I don't want to have to define package.path multiple times though...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I think I figured out what's going on... but I don't know why or how to fix it. If I set the package.path definition at the top of the file, by the time the code gets into the list_devices() method, package.path is reset back to the default value.  I tested this by adding a debug statement that dumps the contents of package.path inside the if statement of the code that's failing.  It no longer has the path I appended on, namely "/usr/share/zaf/mytestapp/?.lua".

This explains why i can't instantiate the object.  Since it seems that I'm not doing something obviously wrong, (i wasn't sure before bc I'm new at lua) I'm going to bark up another tree.  I'm using a framework.  Maybe it has a bug... testing that out right now.

Comment: This is very strange. Could you try making a smaller example? What happens if you get rid of the outer function or the pcall? Additionally, what Lua version are you using?

Comment: You should use `package.config:sub(1,1)` instead of `;`, it's configurable on Lua. Also, `module (..., package.seeall)` is deprecated since 5.1, as I remember.

Comment: @Kamiccolo can you expand a little on your comment about using package.config, please?  thank you.

Comment: @missingno if i get rid of the pcall, the code that doesn't work now fails with an error saying it can't find lib.user... which means the package.path statement at the top of the file is not working.  I'm running lua 5.1.5

Comment: @missingno, please see Edit 1 in my post.  Thank you

Comment: @dot paths separator (in Your and ordinary case is `;`, `some/path;some/another/path;one/more/path`). BUT it's configurable, so, You should use the value returned by `package.config:sub(1,1)`. In case the default value is changed.

Comment: @Kamiccolo, i see what you mean now.  thanks for the clarification. i'll give it a try and post back what i find.

Comment: @Kamiccolo, package.config:sub(1,1) returns "/".  I geuss that means that the way i'm setting package.path is incorrect??

Comment: @dot, oh, sorry, my mistake. That should be `package.config:sub(2,3)`. First simbol - directory separator, not templates. [Relevant part of doc](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.config). (Somehow there is no such a note on Lua 5.1 docs).

Comment: @Kamiccolo, ok that makes more sense.  Now I get "\;" where I guess the backslash is the escape character, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you show. The source of the problem is with code not shown, combined with the use of `pcall` which traps the error in favor of a return code so your script can continue despite error in the anonymous function if you don't take proper precautions. This can be useful but also dangerous (if proper checks aren't in place).

To wit, I run the following `main.lua`:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";testreqdir/?.lua"
list_devices = function(end_user)
    function test()
        if end_user then
            print('requiring')
            local user = require "testlib.user"
            user:test()   
        end
    end
    local status, errMsg = pcall(test)
end
list_devices(true)
```

In the folder `testreqdir/testlib`, the `user.lua` is this:

```
print('user loaded')
return {
    test = function() 
        print('hello', arg[0])
    end
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
C:\Users\me>lua testrequire.lua
requiring
user loaded
hello   testrequire.lua
```

If I comment out the `package.path` line so the `user.lua` module is not found, the output is the following, and there is no indication that an error occured in the call to `require`, due to `pcall`:

```
C:\Users\me>lua testrequire.lua
requiring
```

Most likely when you require your `user.lua` from inside the function, an error occurs but gets trapped by `pcall` and returned as a code. So remove the `pcall` for now so you get a traceback. Also, if you insist on a `pcall`, you should add code to check the return code for err and take appropriate action. You might be interested in `xpcall`, which allows you to set an error handler function; this may lead to cleaner code.

Comment: you're right.  i should have noticed the pcall.  i've removed it for now and sure enough it's complaining that it can't find the library 'lib.user' eventhough i still have the package.path defined right at the top of the module...

Comment: Please see my "EDIT 1" in my post

Comment: Good. I imagine you could search for all occurrences of package.path in framework and your scripts.

Comment: haven't figured out exactly where... but I've proven the framework is clobbering the path.  I'm going to mark yours as the answer... thanks